# Gorm query returning only a single row

Tags: go, go-gorm

We're trying to use Gorm with mysql 8 to much frustration.

I have the following tables (simplified for brevity here)

```
type StoragePool struct {
    gorm.Model
    PoolId  string   `json:"id" gorm:"column:poolid;size:40;unique;not null"`
    Volumes []Volume `json:"volumes" gorm:"foreignkey:StorageId;association_foreignkey:PoolId"`
}

type Volume struct {
    gorm.Model
    StorageId string `json:"storageid" gorm:"column:storageid;size:40"`
}
```

Data insertions seem to work fine. Both tables get populated and no constraints are violated.

A query that expects a single record seems to work fine:

```
poolRecord := &StoragePool{}
if err := tx.Where("poolid = ?", pool.PoolId).First(&StoragePool{}).Scan(poolRecord).Error; err != nil {        
    return err
}
```

This query only returns a single row. When I perform this exact query as raw SQL outside of go, it returns all 31 records I expect.

```
var poolVolumes []Volume
if err := tx.Where("storageid = ?", pool.PoolId).Find(&Volume{}).Scan(&poolVolumes).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
log.Debugf("found %d volumes belonging to %q [%s]", len(poolVolumes), pool.Name, pool.PoolId)
```

According to the docs, that second sql statement is the equivalent of "SELECT * FROM VOLUMES WHERE STORAGEID = 'poolid'". That is not the behavior I am getting.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: sanity check the value : `pool.PoolId` is correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I rarely use an ORM while coding with go, but following the [doc](http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map) from gorm, it seems like you are doing it the wrong way.

`Scan` is used for scanning result into another struct, like this:

```html
type Result struct {
  Name string
  Age  int
}

var result Result
db.Table("users").Select("name, age").Where("name = ?", 3).Scan(&result)
```

The correct way to get query results into a slice of structs should be:

```html
var poolVolumes []Volume
if err := tx.Where("storageid = ?", pool.PoolId).Find(&poolVolumes).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```